# CプログラムのRAMとCPU使用率の確認

Tags: c

Cプログラムまたは任意の言語のプログラムがどれだけのRAMとCPUを占有しているかを確認する方法はありますか？私はあなたがアプリケーションにアクティビティモニタを使用できることを知っています、しかしただ一つのCファイルをチェックする方法はありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Unix系環境の場合

`top -p <pid>`と、`top`に加えてプロセスIDを指定してあげることで、対応するプロセスだけのRAM/CPU使用率を表示し続けることができます。

また、 `top` を使わずに一度だけ表示することも可能です（`while`や`sleep`と組み合わせると良いでしょう。）。

> `ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem,cmd`
>
> [shell - Retrieve CPU usage and memory usage of a single process on Linux? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/retrieve-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux)
>   の [回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221597/10216107) より